# How to compile mutil-modules in idea2020.1 in once time?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-2020

I have a mutil-modules maven project. When I compile the root `pom.xml` in the maven sidebar in idea2020.1, it does not compile all the modules. If I compile the project in terminal with `mvn compile`, it can  compile all the modules.

Question: How to compile mutil-modules using maven compile sidebar in idea2020.1 in once time?

I notice that the console output is different from `mvn compile`：

```
"D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\bin\java.exe" -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=D:\code_repo\demo "-Dmaven.home=D:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.9" "-Dclassworlds.conf=D:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin\m2.conf" "-Dmaven.ext.class.path=D:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven-event-listener.jar" "-javaagent:D:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=7770:D:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "D:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.9\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version2020.1 --debug --non-recursive --update-snapshots -s "D:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.9\conf\settings.xml" -Dmaven.repo.local=D:\repo\repository -DskipTests=true compile
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-11T00:41:47+08:00)
Maven home: D:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.9
Java version: 1.8.0_231, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre
Default locale: zh_CN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
[DEBUG]   Included D:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven-event-listener.jar
[DEBUG] Populating class realm maven.ext
[DEBUG]   Included D:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven-event-listener.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

Choose this option `Execute goals recursively` in `File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment`